# Restrict editing a resource based resource attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The logic of the application that I currently work on demands a `Payment` mustn't be editable if its `status` is `open`. I see two ways of implementing this:

1  A routing constraint like:

```
constraint: lambda { |req| Payment.find(req.id).status != 'open' }
```

2 A simple condition in `PaymentsController#edit`:

```
if @payment.status == 'open'
  redirect_to payments_path
end
```

What option should I go for? Which is more suitable and clean, Rails-ish? Is there any other option? If I go with the first option and have a `resources :payments`, how can I add the constraint only for the edit route?

Comment: 2nd way is well, also protect update action also from changing the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the Rails way of solving this it is actually none of your suggestions.

1. **Routing** - You routes should just simply declaratively state the RESTful interface of your application. They should not be aware of the current request unless absolutely necessary.
2. **Controller** - Adding business logic in the controller will bloat your controllers and violates DRY.

In MVC the model is in charge of enforcing the business logic. You could handle this through a custom validation for example:

```
class Payment
  validates :cannot_be_edited_when_open, on: :update
  def cannot_be_edited_when_open
    errors.add(:status, 'is open. Cannot edit this record.') if self.open?
  end
end
```

This will cause any call to `.update` to fail - which means that you probably will not need to change anything in your controller.

### Edited

Another place to handle this would be on the authorization layer - the key difference here is how the feedback should be handled.

A validation failing will just re-render the form (422 Unprocessable Entity for an API) while an authorization error should clearly tell the user "no you don't have permission to do that - and changing the input won't change that" (403 Forbidden).

To setup the rule in CanCan you would do:

```
can [:edit, :update], Payment do |payment|
  payment.status !== 'open'
end
```

You could also possibly set this up with hash condition instead of a block if your business logic allows it:

```
can [:edit, :update], Payment, status: 'not-open'
```

Comment: I don't use ActiveRecord but Her, that's why I didn't use enums (otherwise I'd have used them). The validation seems indeed clean, but for the user experience wouldn't it be awkward to actually be able to see and submit the edit form? This shouldn't be possible from the first place.

Comment: In that case you would handle it on the the authorization layer. Are you using CanCanCan or Pundit or rolling your own?

Comment: what if the status it self changed, say from 'close' to 'open'?

Comment: @max that's a good argument. I use CanCanCan. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: It depends @leiliu. If you simply assign the status attribute before updating it will work since the validation will look at attribute in memory.

Comment: Edited question with a CanCan example.

Comment: @max, sorry I did't make myself clear, i mean, with this validation, you could never change the status from 'close' to 'open', unless you skip the validation, and I think the requirement should be, only when the original(not target) status is open, it can not be updated.

Comment: Your probably right here @leiliu - you could use the dirty state checking to see what original value is in the validation but we don't know what ORM is being used and if it supports this.  Or you just rely on `update_attribute(state: 'someotherstate') ` which does not care about validations if the state is only updated by something like a worker process. However its not really that relevant since he is doing it on the authorization level instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the rule you specified is a **business logic**, i.e. no `Payment` object should be updated with the status `open`, then, the correct way would be to add that logic to your model. You can use `before_validation` or `before_update` [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Also, don't display any means to `edit` (link, button, etc.) your `Payment`s that have status `open`. If a user somehow gets to your form, display it, but then validation in your model will not let them save it. I think, in this case, everyone is responsible for their own responsibilities.

But, if you have to choose from the 2 options you provided, I would go with the second one. Your first option, having the business logic in routes, doesn't seem not right. It does not belong there, IMO. The second option is better, but the drawback is that you and your team members will still have to remember that they have to check the `Payment` object's `status` attribute does not have some value before touching it. Obviously, someone will forget to do that at some point. So, in the long run, your system (models in your system) will have a *corrupted* state.

Comment: I've missed the idea of just not allowing users to the edit form by _regular_ means. Indeed, if they somehow get to it, the idea is just not to let them perform the actual update. Seems pretty logic.